# Is there any way to detect if a user has added a web app to their home screen?

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, detection

I'm using an iOS springboard "Add to home screen" notification on a site, which appears depending on certain user information. I just don't want my popup to trigger if the user has already added the web app to their home screen.

Is there any way to detect this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see if fullscreen or in a browser using

```
if (navigator.standalone) {
    alert ('Running full screen');
} else {
    alert ('Running in a browser');
}
```

Or an alternative approach would be to look at the window size, to see if there are any chrome around.